# Why is TrackingError function in R PerformanceAnalytics inconsistent with manual calculation using its published formula

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

Using the "managers" dataset in PerformanceAnalytics, the calculation of tracking error seems to be inconsistent to calculating it manually.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#using the managers data set in PerformanceAnalytics

sqrt(sum((managers[,1]-managers[,8])^2)/((length(managers[,1])-1)*sqrt(12)))
TrackingError(managers[,1],managers[,8])
```

my results then are as follows:

```
> sqrt(sum((managers[,1]-managers[,8])^2)/((length(managers[,1])-1)*sqrt(12)))
[1] 0.01760221
> TrackingError(managers[,1],managers[,8])
[1] 0.1131667
```

Interestingly, the package formula does not match the formula in rdrr.io.

According to rdrr.io the formula is:

> TrackingError = sqrt(sum(Ra - Rb)^2 / (length(R) - 1)) * sqrt(scale)

The package formula looks to be:

> sqrt((sum(Ra-Rb)^2)/length(Ra) * sqrt(scale))

I've tried to do this manually in both R and Excel and I can't back into how the TrackingError formula is getting to 11.3%

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be *mostly* resolved by just doing

> sqrt(sum((managers[,1]-managers[,8])^2)/((length(managers[,1])-1)))*sqrt(12)

However, this still doesn't match precisely.

```
> sqrt(sum((managers[,1]-managers[,8])^2)/((length(managers[,1])-1)))*sqrt(12)
[1] 0.1134888
> 
> TrackingError(managers[,1], managers[,8])
[1] 0.1131667
```

**Upon further review, this gets resolved when you think of tracking error as** *standard deviation of the active return* as explained in the wikipedia definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_error.

```
> sqrt(var(managers[,1]-managers[,8]))*sqrt(12)
          HAM1
HAM1 0.1131667
> TrackingError(managers[,1], managers[,8])
[1] 0.1131667
```